# invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm writing iOS app and I've got this error:

Invalid argument type 'void' to unary expression

Here's the code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  //code here
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is on this line?

Comment: Check for imbalance in the parentheses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got your method inside another method's body (maybe you've missed to type its closing `}` ?). That's why you get the error. Try to move it outside somewhere in your `.m` file.

Answer (score 1):

Check the lines *above* your function. Do you have unbalanced parantheses? Did you declare some incomplete statement?

Comment: Nothing. Everything before this line is fine.

Comment: Well, is this the first method declared in this file? If not, what happens if you move the method to the first position?